# how to uninstall activemq in mac os

Tags: macos, activemq-classic

I have activemq 5.15 installed on my mac os, i want to uninstall it, i want to install lower version 5.6. There is no uninstall related files. No instructions are there in http://activemq.apache.org. 
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

'brew uninstall activemq'

i realized that i had installed activemq using 'brew', when i type 'brew list' i can see activemq, so i uninstalled it using 'brew uninstall activemq'.